# how to support url with chinese in nginx

Tags: apache, nginx, url-rewriting

There are some urls following

```
domain.com/hashtag/标签
domain.com/hashtag/tag标签
domain.com/hashtag/tag
```

in nginx, i use rewrite

```
if (!-e $request_filename){
   rewrite (*UTF8)^/hashtag/([A-Za-z0-9_]+)$ /hashtag.php?hashtag=$1;
}
charset utf-8;
```

my system support UTF-8, and all files are in UTF-8, but only the url `domain.com/hashtag/tag` can work well, the other two urls are 502 bad gateway. How can I fix this error? thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry to trouble everyone, i write wrong configure, here it should be

```
   rewrite ^/hashtag/(.*)$ /hashtag.php?hashtag=$1;
```

works well, close this question.

Comment: Hi, you can either delete your question if you want, or accept your own answer in 48 hours when system allows it.

Comment: @MarkusLaire I will accept the answer, maybe someone has the question as this, it will help.